# Using Jdf and Intellij: Specifically running a Jfd form in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jform-designer

I don't really understand how to integrate `jfd` and `intellij`.

So far I have played around with it a little bit and developed a program that looks [image: like this].

I then generated an `actionEventHandler` to handle when the add package button is pressed. For now I just kept it simple and had it output "THIS IS A TEST" into the `outputField` which is the `textField` in the picture above.

the `actionEventHandler` looks like this:

```
private void addPackageButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    outputArea.setText("THIS IS A TEST");
}
```

I would then expect when I did "Test Form" on the jfd tab I would click the `addPackageButton` and it would put "THIS IS A TEST" into the `outputField`.

However, nothing happens. Is this what "Test Form" is for? Or is there another way that I can run my form and test it that I am not seeing? Or is this functionality only available in netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this so I will post this for posterity.

Jfd doesn't add a main to your project by default so adding this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    GUIClassName window = new GUIClassName();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

will allow you to run the module and see the window.